# Collection of intervals of the form $[i/n,j/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, real-numbers

Take the $1/n$-sized uniform partition of $[0,1)$: the set $\left\{\left[\frac{i}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n}\right)\right\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$.

What is the union of all intervals of the form $[i/n,j/n)$, with $i,j \in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$?

For $n=2$, it's $\{[0,1/2), [1/2,1)\} \; \cup \; \{[0,1)\}$.

For $n=3$, it's $\{[0,1/3), [1/3, 2/3), [2/3,1)\} \;  \cup \; \{[0,2/3), [1/3, 1)\} \; \cup \; \{[0,1)\}$

(I've split these into sets of intervals of the same length for organization).

How can we describe this set as $n\rightarrow \infty$? How many times does this union "overlap" $[0,1)$?

Comment: Do you mean "$i,j\in\{0,...,n-1\}$"?

Comment: @C7X yes, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the union only makes sense for $i\neq j$. Thus you want to determine
$$\bigcup_{i,j\in \{0,...,n-1\}}\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right).$$
You can for example decide to first think about a union only looping over $j$, then you get for every $i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$ that
$$\bigcup_{j\in \{0,...,n-1\}}\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)=\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{0}{n}\right)\cup ...\cup \left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right),$$
since the sequence $\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)_{j\in\{0,...,n-1\}}$ is an increasing sequence.
But also $\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)_{i\in\{0,...,n-1\}}$ is an increasing sequence.

Then you get
$$\bigcup_{i\in\{0,...,n-1\}}\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\left[\frac{0}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\cup ...\cup \left[\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\left[0,\frac{n-1}{n}\right).$$ Do you see why above equality is true?

Thus automatically gives the answer for taking $n\to\infty$. Although you have to think about
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{n},$$
which I assume you are familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize that I had worded my answer wrong: of course the union is $[0,1)$ (choose $i=0,j=n-1$). Rather I'm wondering what the set of all those intervals is, including double-counting. I'm not sure what this would describe -- maybe some sort of distribution on $[0,1)$.

Comment: First of all sorry for my late reply, but the set of all such intervals is easy to describe, namely $$\left\{\left[\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)\right\}_{i,j\in\{0,...,n-1\}}=\left\{\left[0,\frac{j}{n}\right),...,\left[\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)\right\}_{j\in\{0,...,n-1\}}=\left\{\left[0,0\right),....,\left[0,\frac{n-1}{n}\right),\left[\frac{1}{n},0\right),...,\left[\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right),...,\left[\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\right\}.$$
I don't know if you are looking for more than this.

Comment: Right, we can describe them but how do we know how many times a certain point $x\in [0,1)$ is covered by those intervals? I'm not sure how to better rephrase my question.

Comment: Do you mean how often a point $x\in [0,1)$ is covered depending on $x$ and $n$?

Comment: yes! I was also thinking this collection of sets might induce a measure on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Then again I have to ask a question back, namely how you want to interpret $\left[\frac{i}{n}, \frac{j}{n} \right) $ for $i>j$?